# Why is this unit attached to the main landing gear not a common unit for towing or pushback?

Tags: towing

Less loading is applied to the fuselage with this method compared to towing or the towbarless way. Why is it not really common?

[image]

I'd like to detail this. There's my point, wouldn't it reduce cycles of loading to the fuselage, less fatigue resulted. Then we can eliminate shear pin & speed limit such stuff, doesn't it ?

In my opinion. For safety. This is much safe then the towing method.

Comment: Wouldn't this need to apply a lot more force since the mains are much closer to the CG/CM than the nose wheel?

Comment: No, it's same of moving a object forward. (except turning)

Comment: Then what about turning? turning plays a huge part in towing aircraft in and out of gates

Comment: What if we bring another car to shear the Nose. They operated together. isn't it better than towing.

Comment: You've got a plane that has _X_ take off mass, and _Y_ rolling resistance in the gear. No matter where the force is applied, it takes the same amount to get it moving...

Comment: I knew it. There's my point, wouldn't it reduce cycles of loading to the fuselage, less fatigue resulted. Then we can eliminate shear pin & speed limit such stuff, doesn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it might not have enough clearance for smaller aircraft, while a towbar would work with pretty much everything.

Also the force you apply needs to be pretty much the same, independent from where you push/pull, as you only need to overcome the rolling resistance of the landing gears. The airframe and landing gears are sized for much larger loads, so there is not a lot of saving in my opinion.

Comment: I think the chearance issue can be solve by another design.

Comment: The clearance on a 737 is only a few feet (see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytwCNmdNNEo) for a sense of scale). Yes, it might be conceivable that someone could design a tug that fits in there (maybe, tugs need a significant amount of mass to have traction, they can't just be arbitrarily small), but the driver wouldn't even be able to sit upright. And the clearance issue is even worse on a regional jet.

Comment: Yes, it is. actually those bottom antennas & valves are big problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you would need two per aircraft to have any meaningful stearing. Towing is generally used to push back from the gate, a time when a tight turn is generally needed so taking advantage of the pivoting nosewheel is a big consideration.

Most aircraft tricycl gear from a Cessna 152 up though an A380 are towed from the nose wheel so designers are well aware of this when laying out nose gear specs.

Comment: Yeah, it does a big advantage. but this is insane of pulling the whole fuselage periodically. Then, manufacturer told you to buy a fuse pin for this and you have to follow it. We had to deal with such stuff. well, incident happen every year.

Comment: @user35367, the fuselage has to withstand much greater loads (from pressurisation and aerodynamic forces), so towing is not a critical factor. The greatest stress is local to the nose gear mount when, indeed, towing starts without brake release.

Comment: @Zeus Previous incidents not only result from towing without brake release. They were caused by maybe a sharp turn, an invisble slope or drifting on wet surface etc. But yes, nose gear withstand the greatest stress. Hence, we have to use fuse pin. somehow it always break. can we stop use them? yeah, I wonder if we might start to use PPU (push unit).